# Random-dot kinematograms implementation in javascript/HTML

Tags: perception, vision, decision-making

I am looking for a "random-dot kinematograms" implementation in javascript/HTML that I can use in web-based experiments. Something like this, where the user can specify the direction using a mouse or slider.

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any, but if you want to collaborate, I could design one for you (or guide a student over a semester if you need something more complicated which cannot be done over a single weekend).